# Replace , with <br>

Tags: javascript, arrays

Been browsing SO for some time since I picked up a programming course, and have found it to be an awesome community and great place for knowledge.

Currently I'm stuck with a JavaScript function that I'm trying to clean up.

I need to have names input into an array, and then when I run a 'start' function, it would display the amount of names as a number, and then show each name on a new line.

I've managed to get it working, however there is a ',' character at the start of each line. I've tried various ways to get around it (using replace and split + join) but had no luck so far.

```
var arrName = [];
var custName;

function start(){
    var totalName = 0;
    var count = 0;

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = " ";

    while(count < arrName.length){
        totalName++;
        count++;
    };
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "The total names in the array are: " + totalName + "<br />" + arrName;
}

function addName(){
    custName = document.getElementById("custname").value;

    if(!custName){
        alert("Empty Name!");
    }
    else{
        arrName.push(custName + "<br>");
        return custName;}
}
```

Comment: In `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "The total names in the array are: " + totalName + "<br />" + arrName;` you're putting an array into the DOM (`arrName`). As array is stringified, `,` is added between each of the elements. Change `arrName` to `arrName.join("<br/>")` and then you can remove `<br>` from `arrName.push(custName + "<br>");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The reason is most likely because you are trying to display `arrName` which is an Array with this code: `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "The total names in the array are: " + totalName + "<br />" + arrName;`
>   Here's what I'd suggest:

```
        var arrName = [];
        var custName;

        function start(){
            var totalName = 0;
            var count   = 0;

            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = " ";

            while(count < arrName.length){
                totalName++;
                count++;
            }
            var strOutput   = "The total names in the array are: ";
            strOutput      += totalName + "<br />" +  arrName.join("<br />");
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = " ";
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = strOutput;
        }

        function addName(){
            custName = document.getElementById("custname").value;

            if(!custName){
                alert("Empty Name!");
            }
            else{
                arrName.push(custName);
                return custName;}
        }
```

> Since there is no need for the WHILE Loop, You can skip it like so:

```
        var arrName = [];
        var custName;

        function start(){
            var totalName   = arrName.length;
            var strOutput   = "The total names in the array are: ";
            strOutput      += totalName + "<br />" +  arrName.join("<br />");
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = " ";
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = strOutput;
        }

        function addName(){
            custName = document.getElementById("custname").value;

            if(!custName){
                alert("Empty Name!");
            }
            else{
                arrName.push(custName);
                return custName;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

An array when console logged or inserted to DOM directly will be represented as `item1,item2,item3,item4`

So simply, `arrName.join("<br />")`

Also, your `while` loop can be simply replaced by

`totalName = arrName.length;
count = arrName.length`